# Java common pool threads get thread group from calling thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread in a thread group "Foo". It uses the common pool of threads to do some work via a parallel stream. Afterwards, the thread group of the common pool threads is also "Foo". Under what circumstances do new threads use the thread group of the thread in which they are constructed? Can this behavior be prevented?

In this example, the output is:

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-31
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-21
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-17
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-27
```

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ThreadGroupTest {
  private static Thread doThreadedWork(ThreadGroup threadGroup) {
    Thread t = new Thread(threadGroup, () -> {
      IntStream.range(0, 500).parallel().forEach(i -> Math.log(Double.valueOf(i)));
    });
    t.start();
    return t;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("Foo");
    doThreadedWork(threadGroup).join();
    Thread.getAllStackTraces()
        .keySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getThreadGroup().equals(threadGroup))
        .forEach(t -> System.out.println(t.getName()));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm look in various implementations of Thread.java and see that the SecurityManager is consulted for the thread group of new threads and if a null is returned then the current thread's thread group is used. I guess this is in the Java spec somewhere.

Comment: Adding a security manager to provide a thread group did not result in the worker threads being put in that group. Instead they were put into a group named InnocuousForkJoinWorkerThreadGroup. I don’t see in the Java source a way to control that.